# SSRS Lookup - Possible To Join on Multiple Columns

Tags: join, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, lookup

I had a question regarding lookups in SSRS. I'm currently using Visual Studio 2012/SQL Server-2012.

I have the following 2 datasets which bring in the following columns:

```
Table 1 Dataset     Table 2 Dataset
Client Number       Loan Client Number
Loan Number         Loan Detail Number
Loan ID             Loan Amount
Borrower Name       Loan Type
```

I'm trying to make my final table in SSRS using lookups in this order:

```
Client Number | Loan Number | Loan ID | Borrower Name | Loan Amount | Loan Type
```

In the case above Client Number (Table 1) = Loan Client Number (Table 2) and Loan Number (Table 1) = Loan Detail Number (Table 2)

Right now, I have a lookup where I only have one join to bring in additional columns:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Loan_Number.Value,Fields!Loan_Detail_Number.Value,Fields!Loan_Amount.Value,"Table_2_Dataset")
```

I know how to do a lookup when joining on 1 column. Is there a way to do a lookup where you join on multiple columns (join on Client Number and Loan Number, in this case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'fields' you join on are just expressions, so you can simply join two (or more) fields together on both sides of the comparison to join. Depending on datatypes, number ranges etc., you might have to do some work to ensure they will be unique but it should be fairly simple.

As an example, if we just joined Client Number 111 and Load Detail Number 1 we would get 1111, however we may have a Client Number 11 with a loan detail number 11 which will also give us 1111.

For the sake of simplicity, lets say that neither number will exceed 999. So our expression to join on would be something like this. *(guessing your field names from your dataset field names)*

((Fields!Client_Number.Value * 1000) + Fields!Loan_Number.Value)

So your full expression would look something like

```
=Lookup(
        ((Fields!Client_Number.Value * 1000) + Fields!Loan_Number.Value),
        ((Fields!Loan_Client_Number.Value * 1000) + Fields!Loan_Detail_Number.Value),
        ,Fields!Loan_Amount.Value
        ,"Table_2_Dataset"
       )
```

Comment: Thank you Alan! Had to adjust a little bit based on what I needed for, but overall your idea worked! Appreciate it.